# Error while trying to pass awk result to variable

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to create a simple bash script to get the HTTP codes from CURL

So here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
AWKRESULT = $(curl -sL -w "result=%{http_code}" "http://192.168.8.69:8080/myReport/archive" -o "/tmp/reportlog" | awk -F= '{print $2}')
echo $AWKRESULT
```

the result of

```
curl -sL -w "result=%{http_code}" "http://192.168.8.69:8080/myReport/archive" -o "/tmp/reportlog" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

is 500.

However it's always has this result :

> ./test.sh[2]: AWKRESULT:  not found.

any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the `=`:

```
AWKRESULT=$(...)
```

Comment: +1 Your bash script has invalid syntax.